# Buttons in chrome extension popup

Tags: button, jquery-selectors, google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm writing a chrome extension in which I want buttons to appear in the popup page as a result of some user's actions (Say, after he logged in to my site through the popup page).
[Documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution) states that inline JavaScript will not be executed and the suggested way to implement it is using

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 document.querySelector('#button1').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

when 'button' is a tag in popup.html.

But here is the thing: I don't want the button to appear when the page is loaded as mentioned. When I try to add button using `$("#some_div").append(<button id="button1">...<button>)` and then to call document.addEventListener, it seems that document.querySelector doesn't find the appended button (In fact it returns null) since it is not part of the original popup.html.

So far, the only solution I thought of is to add the button to popup.html as hidden and set it to visible when needed.

Any other idea (or, hopefully I'm mistaken all together) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create button with `var newButton = document.createElement('button')` and use `appendChild` instead of `append`. Then you can just write `newButton.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've tried the follwing:   
  var newButton = document.createElement('button');
  
  ("#some_div").appendChild(newButton);

but I'm getting the error message on console log: "some_div has no method 'appendChild'

Comment: OK, I figured it out. I had to use the DOM method `document.getElementById("popup").appendChild()`, not `("popup").appendChild()`. Thanks.